# How to Connect to SQL from Management Console using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I have a group of SQL servers spread out in 25 locations that all have the same database.  I can connect to all of them manually using the Management Console.  In the server management console under "New Query", I would like to learn how to wrap a query or a group of t-sql statements with a loop that will first make the connection to one of the servers, specify the database, and then run the query/statement.  This way if I need to run a common query on all of the databases, such as updating the databases, I don't have to manually connect to each one, expand the console, click on the database, and then click "New Query."

The servers are all named wsrv01, wsrv02, wsrv03, etc., so I could loop through the names easily; I just don't know how to do the loop or make the connection.

This is kind of a unique environment...I've used RedGate in the past on other projects and love it; but this is a different situation.

Basically, I want to avoid having to do this and drill into each server to run a query:

[image]

Comment: What does Sql Profiler show if it is running in the background while you connect manually?

Comment: See [Execute Statements Against Multiple Servers Simultaneously (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743.aspx)

Comment: I think what I need is more along the lines of a sql script that creates a connection to the server and database and then executes the t-sql statement within the loop.

Comment: @GaryGerson - Why? What would that give you that the inbuilt functionality doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use anything else.. try to create a linked server. That way you can query the easy way like..

```
select * from <linkedserver>.<database>.<schema>.<object>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Martin Smaith is my prefered solution but I can suggest 2 other ways:

1) You can use the "SQLCMD Mode" in SSMS.

It would look like:

```
:connect MyServer -U MyLogin -P MyComplexPassword
--Then have some code

:connect MyOtherServer ...
--Then have some code
```

But you can't loop that so you will have repetitive code.

Or

2) You can create a CMD file with a FOR loop based on a list of servers. Here's an example of my own brew. Just Copy Paste it to REQ.CMD and create a text file named SERVERS.LST with a server name per line. Connection will be Windows Authenticated. You can change OSQL for SQLCMD if you like but OSQL should work with SQL 2008.

```
REM To execute a SQL command or file to multiple servers
REM Using a server list file
REM And using 2 kind of parameters (script file or query)
REM Pollus Brodeur - June 2007
@echo off

set PARAM1=%1
set PARAM2=%2
set PARAM3=1

REM You need at least 1 parameter
if x==%1x goto ERROR1
if EXIST %PARAM1% (set ISFILE=1) else (set ISFILE=0)

REM Setting Servers List File and verify file existance or X
if x==%2x (set PARAM2=servers.lst)
if X==%2 (set PARAM3=0 & set PARAM2=servers.lst & goto MAIN)
if NOT EXIST %PARAM2% (goto ERROR2)

REM Not interactive
if X==%3 (set PARAM3=0)

:MAIN
echo ===============================================================================
echo REQ - Execute a SQL command or file to multiple servers using a list file
echo %DATE% %TIME%
if %PARAM3%==0 (echo Non Interactive mode)
echo ===============================================================================

if %ISFILE%==0 (GOTO COMMAND)

echo For following file :
echo %PARAM1%
goto EXEC

:COMMAND
echo For following command :
echo %PARAM1%

:EXEC
echo ===============================================================================
echo For following servers :
type %PARAM2%
echo ===============================================================================

if %PARAM3%==1 (echo Interactive mode. Use X parameter to deactivate & pause)

echo Exec...
if NOT EXIST .\out mkdir out
if EXIST out\req.out (del out\req.out)
if %ISFILE%==0 (GOTO COMMAND1)

for /F %%a in (%PARAM2%) do echo %%a & osql -S %%a -E -n -h-1 -w 9999 -u -i %PARAM1% -o out\req.out.%%a.txt
goto ENDEXEC

:COMMAND1
for /F %%a in (%PARAM2%) do echo %%a & osql -S %%a -E -n -h-1 -w 9999 -u -Q %PARAM1% -o out\req.out.%%a.txt

:ENDEXEC
type out\req.out.*.txt >> out\req.out 2>&1
echo ===============================================================================
echo Execution is done. Output files are in .\out
echo more /E /C out\req.out.*.txt
echo more out\req.out
echo ===============================================================================
if %PARAM3%==1 (pause)
goto END

:ERROR1
goto CALLEXAMPLE

:ERROR2
echo Error: Server File List named %PARAM2% doesn't exists
goto CALLEXAMPLE

:CALLEXAMPLE
echo -------------------= REQ call examples =--------------------
echo REQ.cmd Param1 Param2 Param3
echo Param1 = command or scriptfile.sql {mandatory}
echo Param2 = servers list file {servers.lst per default}
echo Param3 = X {for non interactive mode}
echo ------------------------------------------------------------

:END
```